# Chrome plugin for looking up words in a dictionary when you click on them when browsing

Tags: web-browser, chrome, google-apps

I am reading pages with lots of medical terms, many of which I am unfamiliar with. I would like to have the opportunity to see a definition, or list of definitions, from WordReference, or Merriam Webster, or some other dictionary, such as a medical dictionary, or a combination of dictionaries, by clicking on the word (tapping it: as it will not be a hyperlink, the use will need to tap it, not click on it, highlighting it and somewhat using some mechanism summoning the word dictionary). It would be nice if the Chrome plugin even brought up definitions from more than one dictionary or thesaurus, in a vertically scrollable pop-up widget below analogous to the one shown by Google Smart Lock, when Google asks you to save a password.

What Chrome plugin would do this for Android smartphones (I'm running Android 7.0 Nougat)?

Ideally such a plugin would work across a variety of languages although I am particularly interested in Chinese, Italian, Czech, and Maltese.

Thanks.